# PhpMyAdmin #1045

Tags: phpmyadmin, localhost, root, mysql-error-1045

I know other people have had this issue, so please don't mark this as duplicate.

The reason I'm posting this is because, I saw a message saying I should fix loopholes, so I went over to the users pannel, and deleted all users who could use Any for username. Then I gave a password for the rest, and when I pressed go, I get:
Error

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

I googled it, and others DO have this problem, but theirs is happening by accident, I changed mine purposefully to patch a security issue. How can I revert this, so that I can at least still access my pannel?

Comment: can you still access mysql on the commandline using the root user (or another user with enough grant rights)?

Comment: I don't know how to use command line for this, but in PHP, my site using sql is working fine, I used localhost, root, and the password I defined. So, I'd say yes, it's working fine, I just can't access the pannel.

Comment: so in your normal site you use root and a password to access the same MySQL? Then look at your PhpMyAdmin config again, because the message says it is not using a root password. Is there a value for something like $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your /ph-myadmin-directory/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']             = 'my_root_password';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']      = true;
```

Worked for me.